# How to Kill Difficult Task in Mac Terminal

Tags: osx, job-control

I ran this grep:

```
grep -r "\-\-\-foo\-\-\-" * | grep -vi bar
```

For the past 5 minutes my Mac has been running hot (I can hear the fan) and I can't hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> to kill the current task.

Even the clock on my Mac hasn't updated in 6 minutes.

How can I kill the task?

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> always works for me, to suspend the process and resume the shell terminal.

Then

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

or

```
pkill -9 bar
```

usually does the trick.

`[p]kill -9` sends the KILL signal to the process identified by Process ID, or executable name.

On an Ubuntu box, you can substitute <PID> for `jobs -p`, (with backticks), which just prints the process ID of other child processes of the current shell (hopefully only the process just suspended with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>).

On OSX, you have to type in the PID manually, or use `pkill`. You can find other child jobs' PID's with `jobs -l` (`jobs -p` doesn't work on OSX), which prints other information as well as the PID.

In the case that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> doesn't work, open a new terminal window up and identify the process ID with

```
ps aux | grep bar
```

and `[p]kill` as above.

Answer (score 1):

Open new `Terminal`, then type `top` in your `Terminal`. You'll see the list of process running, like in the following image

[image]

You can see the `grep` process id here. then press `q`. It'll come back to terminal again. Then kill the two process using, `kill` command:,

```
kill 4963
kill 4934
```